# Why is there still no hot water after installing new thermostats and elements?

Tags: water, heater

I have just replaced both thermostats and elements in my whirlpool hot water heater.  I have checked voltage on both elements.  I have voltage at all 4 points.  I read that it should only be one at a time.  Checked resistance on both elements and got about 13 ohms. All this checked and still no hot water.  What do I do next?

Comment: I'm not sure what "all 4 points" refers to, but if it's the two ends of two elements, it means that there's no current flowing through the elements. That means that the thermostat is not closing, or there's some other wiring error. Show us a photograph or an accurate drawing of what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

After being sure the water tank is full of water (which would not be the case after replacing an element) and the cutoff valve(s) are on, be sure the power is on.  If you see voltage at the elements, it has got to be heating water.  Unless they were not wired correctly.

If you had just turned it back on, give it 10–20 minutes to detectably heat the water.

A photo of the final wiring arrangement along with make/model information and observed voltages would be very helpful.

Comment: Absolutely check to be sure that the water tank is full, with no air pocket at the top! A heating element suspended within an air pocket will heat no water.